# Using Server.Execute to solve Server.Transfer exception returns two pages

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to solve the dreaded `ThreadAbortException` that happens on `Server.Transfer`. I used the [technique](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629) supplied by Microsoft to use `Server.Execute`. The exception is not thrown any more, but after making the server execute, the response seem to append the current page to the "executed" page.

How can I avoid this while using Server.Execute?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No valid answer seems to be found.

Comment: Has any solution ever been found for this? I just ran into the same problem and seeing your question/answer is very discouraging.

Answer (score 1):

this worked well for me and caused no exceptions:
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("~/ErrorAppDown.aspx", false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

That is what `Server.Execute()` does. It calls another page just like a method call. And after other page's execution is completed, it starts executing itself. Thus, appending itself after executed page. You have to end response to stop this from happening.

Comment: I used `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` as suggested by MS, but it doesn't seem to do any effect.

Comment: Is it `Response.End()` that is causing an `Exception` in your code? If not, try using it.